# How to display php form result in the html if php processing is not in the same page without using ajax?

Tags: php, html, forms

Lets say i have this form in `form.php` file.

```
<form action="process.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="message">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<span class="result"></span>
```

`process.php` contains

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['message'])){
  $message = $_POST['message'];
  if(!empty($message)){
    echo 'Your message: '.$message;
  }else{
    echo 'Please enter some message.';
  }
}
```

Now if i want to display the output of `process.php` inside the `form.php`'s span tag of class `result` i either need to use ajax, or session/cookie or file handling. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply place the code in the `process.php` file inside the forms span tag.

```
<form action="form.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="message">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<span class="result">
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['message']))
    {
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        if(!empty($message))
        {
            echo 'Your message: '.$message;
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'Please enter some message.';
        }
    }
?>
</span>
```

Comment: My form and php processing should be in two different files

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It will post the form values in same page

```
<form action="form.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="message">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<span class="result"></span>

<?php 
if(isset($_POST['message'])){
  $message = $_POST['message'];
  if(!empty($message)){
    echo 'Your message: '.$message;
  }else{
    echo 'Please enter some message.';
  }
}
```

Comment: it makes the html and php processing in the same page, which i am not looking for

Answer (score 0):

OK this is one way of doing it: In `form.php`,

```
<form action="process.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="message">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php
    $var = $_GET['text'];
    echo "<span class=\"result\"> $var </span>";
?>
```

Then in `process.php` do this:

```
<?php 
   if(isset($_POST['message'])){
    $message = $_POST['message'];
      if(!empty($message)){
         // echo 'Your message: '.$message;
         header("location: form.php?text=$message")
      }else{
        echo 'Please enter some message.';
      }
}
?>
```

There are a few drawbacks using this method:

1. Variable $message is passed through the URL and so should not be too long    as URLs have length limits
2. Using $_GET[] makes message visible on the URL so passwords and other sensitive information should no be used as the message.

I hope this helps.